# Handling ruby Float like java

Tags: java, ruby, programming-languages

if i make a function that simply return a double value like this

```
double example () 
{
   double i =  999999999;
   return i;
}
```

the output will be:

example() => 9.99999999E8

i don't know how to obtain it with ruby.. can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just turn it into a float, you can use `to_f`, for displaying in scientific notation a format string will help:

```
>> 999999999.to_f #=> 999999999.0
>> "%E" % 999999999 #=> "1.000000E+09"
```

Comment: it is impossible to obtain the same value as java? (9.99999999E8)  because i need to obtain exactly 9.99999999E8 from 999999999

Comment: It's just being displayed differently. For example, ("%.7E" % 999999999.0) displays "9.999999999E+08". I don't know if there is a display setting to change E+08 into E8, but check the printf documentation here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Answer (score 1):

For your example, use a float literal instead of an integer literal. That is, type 999999999.0 or 9.99999999e8 instead of 999999999. If it's in a variable instead (e.g. x), use x.to_f:

```
def f()
    999999999.0
end
```

or

```
def f()
    (999999999).to_f
end
```

Comment: it is impossible to obtain the same value as java? (9.99999999E8)  because i need to obtain exactly 9.99999999E8 from 999999999

Comment: You are. (999999999).to_f gives exactly 9.99999999E8. Or do you mean the format? Ruby does display the numbers differently. There's nothing you can do about that except write your own formatting function, since there is no option to change it.